# Get visual graph of heap memory usage in Java over a span of time

Tags: java, memory-management

I am currently using Visual VM to monitor the heap memory usage of my Java application. However I would like to somehow see the heap memory usage over a span of time like for example a day and not just get a snapshot.I would like to be able to leave Visual VM or a tool on and let it log the memory usage and then later after one day, I can go back and see a graph of it. Is there a way to do this using Visual VM? If yes, how? If not, what tool can I used to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run your Java program with the following Java options:

```
-Xloggc:log.out -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

and download [HPjmeter](http://www.hpjmeter.com) to visualize `log.out`.

Also see SUN's [GC portal](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/GCPortal/) webpage for more options to run with.  Since the data is written to a file, you won't have any problems collecting days or weeks worth of data.  Of course, if you wish to visualize data with lots of information, you'll need to run HPjmeter with more memory.

Your other option is to use [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html).

Comment: It seems to me that they are gc logs. Aren't they logged only every time a memory peak occurs?

Comment: @Jeune - The GC logs show you Heap Utilization after GC, probably the most accurate measure of your Java heap usage.  It has nothing to do with memory peak.  Try it out...

Comment: Is the GC called, and eventually logged, that often for me to be able to graph an accurate heap memory usage over a certain span of time?

Comment: @Jeune - Unless you statically allocate all objects in your application up front and they never go out of scope and your program has no short lived objects

Comment: @Jeune You can also try JConsole as I suggested.

Comment: Jconsole seems to do the trick but can I save the current heap memory usages I am getting and open them at a later time?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure you'll have to experiment with that one.  With HPjmeter you can do that.  Not only that, but you can take two different runs and compare the memory usage!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Memory tab in JConsole. JConsole is also included with the Oracle JDK, like JVisualVM, so you should already have it. It has a time range of "all" which should work for what you want to do. It will look like this:

[image: screenshot of jconsole]