# Visualize java memory usage over time

Tags: java, linux, memory, profiling

On Linux, I want to run java .jar file from command line and produce some output about memory usage over time that can be later visualize in some program. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316649/get-visual-graph-of-heap-memory-usage-in-java-over-a-span-of-time), but `HPjmeter` is unable to load produced `log.out` file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can try [jvisualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html).

Comment: I tried but it also wasn't able to open this file.

Comment: Have you tried JConsole? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html